# Can EE be installed on my PC for learning

Tags: install

I'd like to be able to install EE on my PC so I can experiment and learn.  Can this be done?

thank you!!

Comment: You will need Apache server and mysql database.  You can use easyphp but there other option.  About the EE license i don't know but i guess you can.

Answer (score 0):

IDownload  and nstall the WampServer

http://www.wampserver.com/en/download-wampserver-32bits/

You can read this tutorial about Wamp:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-wampserver/

So read the install ExpressionEngine documentation:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/index.html

Good luck